# Правильно ли написали в свидетельстве рождении ребенка?

Tags: канцеляризмы

Правильно ли написали в свидетельстве рождении ребенка?
"Родился 
Четырнадцатого июля двухтысячного года".

Comment: в свидетельстве О рождении

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то числительное должно писаться с маленькой буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Ну это только родители знают, правильно ли. 
С точки зрения русского языка тут ошибок нет, оформительские правила - это в загсах, думаю, знают лучше. Вот разве число и год сейчас где-то еще пишут прописью?

Comment: Пишут - во всех нотариальных документах, недавно доверенность оформляла, заставили написать прописью

Comment: Правда? Я от нотариусов что называется "не вылезаю", не обращал внимания. 
Сейчас гляну. 
Не обнаружил ничего похожего. Ладно, я на днях как раз буду, проверю )))